# Can't join my friend in mc and he lives in the uk

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend in Minecraft can join my world but I can't join his. He tried to invite me, but I don't see the notification pop up. I switched to Android recently and can't see the invite things that used to pop up when I used iOS. What's weird is that my nearby friend can join him, but I can't join my other friend who lives in the UK. How can I join him?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in your multiplayer settings that:

- **Multiplayer Game** is **ON**
- **Allow Friends** is **ON**

Then make sure that you have added him as a friend.

The fact that he is in the UK should not matter to my knowledge.